# Configure pagination in codeigniter template system

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, frameworks, pagination

I've created a paginated page that runs well. But after I put it into a template, it gives an error. How do I configure it ?

This is my template library :

```
class Template {
    var $template_data = array();

    function set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->template_data[$name] = $value;
    }

    function load($template = '', $view = '' , $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {               
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->set('contents', $this->CI->load->view($view, $view_data, TRUE));         
        return $this->CI->load->view($template, $this->template_data, $return);
    }
}
```

Default view template :

```
    <div id="header">
     <?php $this->load->view('admin/layout/header');?>  
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
     <?php $this->load->view('admin/layout/sidebar');?> 
    </div>
    <div id="content"><?= $contents ?></div>
    <div id="footer">
     <?php $this->load->view('admin/layout/footer');?>  
    </div>
```

pagination method :

```
function paging_kategori(){
    if (isset($_POST['tblcari'])) {
        $data['ringkasan'] = $this->input->post('cari');
        // se session userdata untuk pencarian, untuk paging pencarian
        $this->session->set_userdata('sess_ringkasan', $data['ringkasan']);
    }
    else {
        $data['ringkasan'] = $this->session->userdata('sess_ringkasan');
    }
    $total = 4;
    $this->load->model('mkategori');
    $this->db->like('nama_kategori', $data['ringkasan']);
    $this->db->from('kategori');

    $config['per_page'] = $total;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'ckategori/paging_kategori';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results();
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm' style='position:relative; top:-25px;'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3,0);
    $data['hasil'] = $this->mkategori->get_data_paging($config['per_page'],$offset,$data['ringkasan']);
    $data['offset'] = $offset;
    //$this->load->vars($data);
    $this->template->load('admin/template','admin/vkategori',$data);
}
```

I think the error occurred on `$config [' base_url ']`. How to set it up if I want to display the paginated page into the template system ?

Comment: Does it work, if you use site_url() instead of base_url() for the base_url config?

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = site_url().'ckategori/paging_kategori';

Comment: does not work ... ... Here I have a page view contains a table that is paginated and then I want to call into the content of templates

Comment: the page it works fine if I load without using the template system.. but become error when I call into the template

Answer (score 0):

Solved ----- i change url_segment into `$config['uri_segment'] = 4;` and `$offset = $this->uri->segment(4,0);`